# angular js : two controller shared asynchrone data

Tags: angularjs

Difficult for me to explain my problem but I'll try to do my best.
I have a form with a controller A and a directive with ng-transclude with a controller B.
When I start the script I'm sending an ID parameter and I call a service that make a $http.get . I made a promise

controller A :

```
 if($routeParams.id){
    formFunc.get($routeParams.id).then(
      function (data){
         this.data = data;
         console.log("1"+this.data);
      }
    );
 }  
 console.log("2"+this.data);
```

controller B :

```
 this.fields = $scope.data.fields; 
 console.log("3"+$scope.data.fields);
```

I have in console : 2 undefined -> 3 undefined -> 1 Object
So I retrieve well the data in controller A but without any binding with controller B.
Data is an object {"fields": {...},"title":...}

Hope the problem is clear

Comment: Your data is loaded asynchronously, so the console logs you're seeing are normal. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't retrieve data in controller B, so it doesn't appear in my form

Comment: You have to setup a $watch in $scope.data to check if the variable as some change, due to the asynchronous loading.

Comment: Why to setup a $watch if i know with the condition if($routeParams.id) that I have to load data ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand that $scope is local to each controller.

**To share to data between controllers you can to use services Or events.**

- Using a service set data from you controller A.

  ```
  if($routeParams.id){
  formFunc.get($routeParams.id).then(
    function (data){
       this.data = data;
       console.log("1"+this.data);
       fromFunc.setData(data); // <---- better, do the setting inside fromFunc, just to show you 
    });
   }
  ```
- watch for the changes in this service from controller B

  ```
  $scope.$watch(
     function(){
        return fromFunc.getData();
     }, 

     function(newValue, oldValue){
      if(oldValue !== newValue){
         $scope.data = newValue; // <----- getting the data from service when data changes.
      }
  })
  ```